# Converting Html.action link to a regular link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code generated by default from asp.net mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { item.ORG_ID  })
```

But I am using an open source web template where I can display a user friendly button such as:-

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
<i class="icon-zoom-in icon-white"></i>
View
</a>
```

So my question is ; how I can convert the `html.actionlink` to be `<A>` link
Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Details", new { item.ORG_ID  })">
    <i class="icon-zoom-in icon-white"></i>
    View
</a>
```

Comment: but this will generate something as /Details/Details?ORG_ID=1. while the html.actionlink will add the current controller to the link. While thi href="@Url.Action("Details", "customer", new { item.ORG_ID  } will work fine

Comment: You can use the method UrlHelper.Action without controller name parameter. The method will add the current controller to the link. I correct my answer, sorry.